# how to filter a DF groupby object to a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, smtplib

I am filtering a dataframe and sending the results of the info in an email using smtplib.
Here's what I got so far.

```
def SMTP_Emailer(content, receiver):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = "Test Email!"
    msg['From'] = 'test@example.com'
    msg['To'] = [receiver]

    msg.set_content( f""" This is a test email, please disregard{content}
        """,  subtype='html')


    with smtplib.SMTP('sendsmtp.server.com', 1234) as s:
                s.send_message(msg)
```

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
d = 
  STATE   CUSTOMER      ORDERS     EMAIL OWNER
0    ID   Jerry         10        Jerry@example.com  
1    MT   Tom           119       Jerry@example.com
2    CA   Patrick       87        Jerry@example.com
3    WA    Lucy         918       Mark@example.com
```

Then Im grouping by the series d['EMAIL OWNER']

```
grouped = df.groupby("EMAIL TEST")
    for emails, data  in grouped:
        print(emails)
        dataframes = [emails for e, group in grouped]
        print(dataframes)
        SMTP_Emailer(data.loc[:, :].to_html(), dataframes)
```

Im expecting ['Jerry@example.com ', 'Mark@example.com '] so that I can put them in my msg['To']

but I'm unexpectedly  getting  ['Mark@example.com ','Mark@example.com '] in VS Code

and in jupyter notebook I'm getting:

```
Mark@example.com
['Mark@example.com', 'Mark@example.com']
Jerry@example.com
['Jerry@example.com', 'Jerry@example.com']
```

Result outcome is 2 separate emails to occur. I used the groupby to filter from the main data source(d)  by the persons email address so that they'd only see what was owned by them and not the other person. So Mark wouldnt see Jerry's data (and the other way around)

Let me know if this helps clarify things.

```
#Email 1  gets sent to Jerry@example.com

Email 1 = 
 
  STATE   CUSTOMER      ORDERS     EMAIL OWNER
0    ID   Jerry         10        Jerry@example.com  
1    MT   Tom           119       Jerry@example.com
2    CA   Patrick       87        Jerry@example.com

#Email 2  gets sent to Mark@example.com

Email 2 =

3   WA    Lucy         918       Mark@example.com
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want `dataframes` to be. How many emails do you want to send to each email address? Is the fix simply `SMTP_Emailer(data.loc[:, :].to_html(), emails)` since the 2nd argument to your func should be the email address?

Comment: I wanted dataframes to create a list of the Emails in df['Email TEST'] Because I think im only getting 1 email back doing SMTP_Emailer(data.loc[:, :].to_html(), **emails**) instead of both.

Comment: Show us what you want

Comment: thanks for clarifying, but I'm still a little confused. how many emails do you want to send to each address?

Comment: Could you clarify the expected output? Why do you need the groupby in the first place?

Comment: Things do not need to be in a groupby! I'm new to python so maybe what makes more is doing a for loop on 'EMAIL OWNER' and then doing a .loc filter for finding that persons name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you solved your problem! I just wanted to show how you could have used groupby if you were still interested. In your answer you pretty much made a groupby (!):

```
for email,dfuser in df.groupby('EMAIL OWNER'):
    SMTP_Emailer(dfuser.to_html(), email)
```

Comment: that makes sense too! thank you for posting

Answer (score 1):

So the groupby was a mistake. It was a lot easier to write the code like this and then filter the data frame for the user that I wanted. I realized I was making copies of the dataframe that already existed.  Here's the final code:

```
    for email in df['EMAIL OWNER'].unique().tolist():
        dfuser = df.loc[df[' EMAIL OWNER'] == email]

        SMTP_Emailer(dfuser.to_html(), email)
```